# I need to search multiple answers for one variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, multidimensional-array

The code below is trying to open a pop-up screen depending on what "result" equals. The report this command button is in has multiple rows for "PassFail". My goal is to search every row and to have different pop-ups for different results. For example, if any "PassFail" equals "fail" or is blank, the first pop-up message. If all "PassFail" equals "Pass", the second pop-up message. Please help!!!

```
Dim result As Variant
result = DLookup("PassFail", "dbo_TestDetail", "dbo_TestDetail.TDIndex" = " & Me!Index & ")

Dim Msg, Style, Title

If result = "Fail" Or Null Then

    Msg = "The test data for S/N " & Me!SN & " has nonconforming values. The TDS will not be approved."
    Style = vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2
    Title = "TDS Approval Denied"

ElseIf result = "Pass" Then
    Msg = "Are you sure you want to approve the test data for S/N " & Me!SN & "?"
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2
    Title = "TDS Approval"

End If
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code?

Comment: Where is the code calling MsgBox?

Comment: The message box will be "The test data for S/N " & Me!SN & " has nonconforming values. The TDS will not be approved." for all conditions. When I hover over result, result = null even though it should = "Pass".

Comment: You say 'report' has command button but reports in PrintPreview are not interactive. Did you mean form or are you running report in ReportView?

Comment: Yes, it is a form opened with acViewReport

Answer (score 0):

Can't compare anything to Null and certainly can't simply `Or Null`.

`If result = "Fail" Or IsNull(result) Then`